# Ubuntu no Internet after using EXPORT https proxy= commands

Tags: networking

Yes, I'm a new Ubuntu user (several versions).

I got "launchpad" errors and so I was trying to solve it with answers posted  in this website.

I found the following commands and  after I ran them, I lost my connection to the internet!

**

```
export https proxy=
export http_proxy=
export https_proxy=$(echo $htpp_proxy | sed 'sed 's/http:/https:/'
```

**

Now I don't know if I did something to my network with those commands. 
I seem to have an IP number but no connection to the Internet.

**Is there a way to restore the original settings by command again so I can have my internet back?**
**Also, can someone explain that last command above?**

I'm sure all three commands got me offline  but I need to UNDO them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unset https proxy
unset http_proxy
```

If you want to configure a proxy via the CLI (on a server) juste use

```
export http_proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Don't export https_proxy=https://youproxy ! Your proxy is probably not SSL

If you use networkmanager, gnome, kde ... just configure it inside
If you use a webbrowser, you can configure it inside